# javascript submit is not passing POST values in IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I have a small piece of code that is not working for IOS devices (iPad, iPhone) because is not passing post values to php backend application.

Here is the code:

```
<form  name="download_0" method="post" action="some_action">
    <button class="pull-right btn-download" onclick="$('[name=download_0]').submit();">Download</button>
    <div class="file_name">
        <div class="file_button">
            <input type="hidden" name="file" id="file" value="file_1.mp3">
            <input type="hidden" name="folder" id="folder" value="folder_1">
            <a href="#" onclick="$('[name=download_0]').submit();"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>
            <a class="download-file" href="#" onclick="$('[name=download_0]').submit();"> filename_1
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form  name="download_1" method="post" action="some_action">
    <button class="pull-right btn-download" onclick="$('[name=download_1]').submit();">Download</button>
    <div class="file_name">
        <div class="file_button">
            <input type="hidden" name="file" id="file" value="file_2.mp3">
            <input type="hidden" name="folder" id="folder" value="folder_1">
            <a href="#" onclick="$('[name=download_1]').submit();"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>
            <a class="download-file" href="#" onclick="$('[name=download_1]').submit();"> filename_2
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is working perfectly in android devices and desktop, even in Safari for non mobile devices.

Someone could help me or give me a clue?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: if it happens when clicking on the link versions of your buttons it maybe that it is doing a page navigation and interrupting the form submit call. Also why are you doing `$('[name=download_0]').submit()` in the first place, and not just putting in an actual form submit button

Comment: I’m using the JavaScript submit because is a requirement to click in some links to download the file (not only in the button). As far as I know is going correctly to the action but when I debug the post values I’m not receiving nothing (only with iOS devices).